# Strange behavior when changing default shell, and setting explorer.exe as winlogon shell for specific user

Tags: windows-7, windows-shell

I use a custom logon shell on a machine (windows 7) for security reasons - which works fine by altering
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell`.

However, I also want that the administrator will still be able to manage the machine, so I modified the user specific key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell
```

back to explorer.exe - but when I log on I get a single windows explorer window, and not the full desktop.

does any one know how to configure the normal desktop shell only to a specific user?